# How to make comment-dwim comment from cursor position if its middle of the line?

Tags: comment

I am using `comment-dwim-line` to comment out multiple lines. For this, I automatically move cursor always to the beginning of a line. I just want to use this behavior if the cursor is at beginning of a line or multiple line is selected.

If the cursor is in the middle of a line, I just want to add a comment character where the cursor is located.

The code I am using:

```lisp
(defun comment-dwim-line (&optional arg)
  "Replacement for the comment-dwim command.
        If no region is selected and current line is not blank and we are not at the end of the line,
        then comment current line.
        Replaces default behaviour of comment-dwim, when it inserts comment at the end of the line."
  ;; http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/emacs-devel@gnu.org/10971693.html
  (interactive "*P")
  (comment-normalize-vars)
  (if (and (not (region-active-p)) (not (looking-at "[ \t]*$")))
      (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
    (comment-dwim arg)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-;") 'comment-dwim-line)
```

Here it is possible to apply normal comment out behavior if the cursor is not at the beginning of a line:

```markdown
def main():
    x = 10   
  (^)
   |__ cursor is here when `comment-dwim-line` is applied it becomes
```

This is `ok`.

```
def main():
    # x = 10
```

---

But for the following example:

```markdown
def main():
    x = 10   my commment
          (^)
           |__ cursor is here when `comment-dwim-line` is applied

    # x = 10   my commment
```

It becomes:

```markdown
def main():
    # x = 10  my commment
```

wanted behavior would be: `x = 10 # my commment` as:

```markdown
def main():
    x = 10 # my commment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentally, changing `(line-beginning-position)` to `(point)` in the arg list of `comment-or-uncomment-region` gives the behaviour you describe:

```lisp
(defun comment-dwim-line (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (comment-normalize-vars)
  (if (and (not (region-active-p)) (not (looking-at "[ \t]*$")))
      (comment-or-uncomment-region (point) (line-end-position))
    (let ((comment-column (current-column)))
      (comment-dwim arg))))
```

Comment: This works close to what I wanted. But when I run this at the end of a line, it adds the comment character to very long distancle like: `pid = os.getpid()                  #`  is this normal?

Comment: Sounds a bit strange, what would you want to be commented out in this circumstance?

Comment: I just want `#` to be added to end of line right after the latest character but it adds `.                          #` instead of just `#`. Like if the cursor is at the end of the line and if there is no character after it ; it adds many empty space followed by `#`

Comment: I've edited the function so it doesn't add extra whitespace when at the end of a line (by temporarily setting `comment-column`)

Comment: Thanks but the updated edit does still add extra whitespace in the case I try to explain :-(

Comment: Thanks but the updated edit does still add extra whitespace and comments are not added to begining of the first character `<cursor>         first_character` becomes `<cursor>#    first_character` instead of `<cursor>    # first_character`

Comment: I get `pid = os.getpid()<cursor>` -> `pid = os.getpid() # <cursor>` and `<cursor>    pid = os.getpid()` ->  `    # pid = os.getpid()`, are both of these not what you expect?

Comment: Yeah but when there is tab before `<tab>pid = os.getpid()`, comment added before the tab not after.

Comment: I can't reproduce that unfortunately - I find the comment character indented regardless of whether I use tabs or spaces